# Is it possible to pass a java.util.Stream to Gson?

Tags: json, stream, gson, java-stream

I'm currently working on a project where I need to fetch a **large amount of data** from the `Database` and parse it into a *specific* Json format, I already have built my custom Serializers and Its working properly when i pass a List to `Gson`. But as I was already working with `Streams` from my `JPA` Layer, I thought I could pass the Stream down to the `Gson` parser so that it could transform it directly to my Json data. But I'm getting an empty Json object instead of a correctly populated one.

So, if anyone could point to me a way to make `Gson` work with `Java 8 Streams` or if this isn't possible currently.. i could not find anything on *Google*, so i came to *Stackoverflow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`JsonWriter`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) to streaming your data to output stream:

```
public void writeJsonStream(OutputStream out, Stream<DataObject> data) throws IOException {
     try(JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"))) {
          writer.setIndent("    ");
          writer.beginArray();
          data.forEach(d -> {
              d.beginObject();
              d.name("yourField").value(d.getYourField());
              ....
              d.endObject();
          });
          writer.endArray();
     }
}
```

Note that you're in charge of controling the json structure.

That is, if your `DataObject` contains nested Object, you have to write `beginObject()/endObject()` respectively. The same goes for nested array.

Comment: So it seems it cannot be made 'natively' with Gson then...
I decided to Collect my streams as Lists for now, but as soon as I have enough time to figure out how to work with JsonStreams I will migrate my solution to it.. Its suposed to be faster than the normal serialization method isn't?

I will mark you answer as correct, as it seems to be the only choice I have. Thanks for you time.

Comment: What's `natively` are you referring to? Btw, this suppose to a lot faster than the way to "collect to a list" then convert to json, since we don't need to load the whole collection into memory, we write the collection to the json stream one by one :D. Cheer.

Comment: I mean natively, without the need to make a hack to resolve my problem.. And i suppose you're right.. i will surely have a look at using JsonStreams, and will surely have a bit of work because of the complexity of the Json i have to build.. but its probably worth it anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is not as trivial as one would expect, but it can be done in a generic way.

When you look into the Javadoc to `TypeAdapterFactory`, they provide a very simplistic way of writing a `TypeAdapterFactory` for a custom type. Alas, it does not work as expected because of problems with element type detection. The proper way to do this can be found in Gson-internal `CollectionTypeAdapterFactory`. It is quite complex, but taking what's necessary one can come up with something like that:

```
final class StreamTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    Type type = typeToken.getType();
    Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();

    if (!Stream.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
      return null;
    }

    Type elementType = ExtraGsonTypes.getStreamElementType(type, rawType);
    TypeAdapter<?> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType));
    return (TypeAdapter<T>) new StreamTypeAdapter<>(elementAdapter);
  }

  private static class StreamTypeAdapter<E> extends TypeAdapter<Stream<E>> {

    private final TypeAdapter<E> elementAdapter;

    StreamTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<E> elementAdapter) {
      this.elementAdapter = elementAdapter;
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter out, Stream<E> value) throws IOException {
      out.beginArray();
      for (E element : iterable(value)) {
        elementAdapter.write(out, element);
      }
      out.endArray();
    }

    public Stream<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      Stream.Builder<E> builder = Stream.builder();
      in.beginArray();
      while (in.hasNext()) {
        builder.add(elementAdapter.read(in));
      }
      in.endArray();
      return builder.build();
    }
  }

  private static <T> Iterable<T> iterable(Stream<T> stream) {
    return stream::iterator;
  }
}
```

The `ExtraGsonTypes` is a special class that I used to circumvent package-private access to `$Gson$Types.getSupertype` method. It's a hack that works if you're not using JDK 9's modules - you simply place this class in the same package as `$Gson$Types`:

```
package com.google.gson.internal;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class ExtraGsonTypes {

  public static Type getStreamElementType(Type context, Class<?> contextRawType) {
    return getContainerElementType(context, contextRawType, Stream.class);
  }

  private static Type getContainerElementType(Type context, Class<?> contextRawType, Class<?> containerSupertype) {
    Type containerType = $Gson$Types.getSupertype(context, contextRawType, containerSupertype);

    if (containerType instanceof WildcardType) {
      containerType = ((WildcardType)containerType).getUpperBounds()[0];
    }
    if (containerType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      return ((ParameterizedType) containerType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    return Object.class;
  }
}
```

(I filed an [issue about that in GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1334))

You use it in the following way:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new StreamTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(Stream.of(1, 2, 3)));
```